# Set Image.Source to file in external storage in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a picture of item in external storage (that was saved by intent in my app). I want to display this picture in `Image` view in my shared project.

`Image.Source` takes object of `ImageSource` type. I tried `ImageSource.FromFile`, `ImageSource.FromStream` and even `ImageSource.FromUri`. The result is always that image is not displayed (no error or exception). I validated that the path to file is correct by first opening it with `File.Open` one line above.

What is the correct way of displaying pictures from normal storage, not from assets/resources/etc?

This code **does not work**:

```
var path = "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/6afbd8c6-bb1e-49d3-838c-0fa809e97cf1.jpg" //in real app the path is taken from DB
var image = new Image() {Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit, WidthRequest = 200, HeightRequest = 200};
image.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(path);
```

Comment: Your application is only for Android?

Comment: @jzeferino At first yes. But I believe that even for iOS if I get this path from my own application then for iOS version it will also be correct and available to read.

Comment: In final version I want to store the images in application private folder, not external storage. So also the solution can read from for example `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Xamarin Forms PCL don't know what its a URI from Android beacuse its platform specific, so:

```cs
ImageSource.FromFile(path);
```

won't work.

In that case you are handling platform specific features, that is loading an image from Android.
I suggest this approach:

Create an interface on Xamarin Forms PCL like:

```cs
public interface IPhoto
{
    Task<Stream> GetPhoto ();
}
```

Then in Android you implement that interface and register the implementation in `DependencyService`:

```cs
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(PhotoImplementation))]
    namespace xpto
    {
        public class PhotoImplementation : Java.Lang.Object, IPhoto
        {
            public async Task<Stream> GetPhoto()
            {
                // Open the photo and put it in a Stream to return       
                var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

                using (var source = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path))
                {
                    await source.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                }

                return memoryStream;
            }
        }
    }
```

In the Xamarin Forms PCL code get the image:

```cs
var image = ImageSource.FromStream ( () => await DependencyService.Get<IPhoto>().GetPhoto());
```

For more detail you can consult [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/text-to-speech/).

**NOTE1: This will work on iOS if you implement the interface IPhoto too.**

**NOTE2: There exist a helpful library for this kind of features from Xamarin-Forms-Labs called [Camera](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/Camera).**

---

**UPDATE (Shared Project solution)**

As requested in the comments, to use this in a Shared Project instead of PCL we could do this.

1 - Place the `IPhotoInterface` in the Shared Project.

2 - Implement the interface in Android/iOS project:

```cs
public class PhotoImplementation : IPhoto
{
    public async Task<Stream> GetPhoto()
    {
        // Open the photo and put it in a Stream to return. 
    }
}
```

3 - Use it in the Shared Project:

```cs
IPhoto iPhotoImplementation;

#if __ANDROID__
iPhotoImplementation = new shared_native.Droid.GetPicture();

#elif __IOS__
iPhotoImplementation = new shared_native.iOS.GetPicture();

#endif

var image = ImageSource.FromStream ( () => await iPhotoImplementation.GetPhoto());
```

NOTE: `shared_native` is the namespace of my solution and `Droid/iOS` are the projects for Android and iOS.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this in two hours, but I use shared projects instead of PCL. I hope it will work also.

Comment: Why you are using shared project? I'f you have any trouble please let me know. Since you are using shared projects you could do this with an #ifdef to. I'n my opinion you should use PCL.

Comment: I investigated both approaches and shared project seemed more convenient for me. People also said that anything that can be done with PCL can be done with shared project. I hope it's true :). Switching to PCL is an option, but only if shared project approach will completely fail. If you have time to add #ifdef version to your answer I would very appreciate :).

Comment: I added a shared project solution to the answer.

Comment: I implemented this and my `GetPhoto` returns `Stream` of correct length, but when assigning it (`_image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => pictureGetter.GetPhoto(_item.PicturePath));` the image is not displayed. I think this solution is quite similar to what I used before (`new FileStream(_item.PicturePath, FileMode.Open)` in shared project, and it doesn't work the same way. I must be missing something with Stream sources...

Comment: Why yout GetPhoto needs a parameter? It should't need a parameter. I teste my solution in both, PCL and Shared Project. It worked. If you set the imagesource from a web URI does the photo is shown?

Comment: `ImageSource.FromUri` with URL of some image from internet works and shows the image. I sent path of picture as parameter as each item has it's own picture assigned. It's kept in the DB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114455/discussion-between-jzeferino-and-episodex).

Comment: For me `ImageSource.FromFile(path);` is working perfectly fine with an Android specific file path. No need for dependency service.