# ImageSource.FromStream() not working on some Android devices

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an `Image` element on my content page. I want to assign `MemoryStream` source to it in constructor of my `ContentPage`. This works ok on Samsung Galaxy A3 (Android 5.0.2) but displays nothing (no error, no exception, no image) on Samsung Galaxy Note 3 (Android 5.0). Is it a bug in Xamarin.Forms? Or do I do something wrong?

Code:

```
Image image = new Image();
var path = "some/path/to/image.jpg";
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path); //has correct byte array with correct length
image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(bytes));
```

Comment: Please try this on emulator and tell us the result.

Comment: I tried on API23 emulator but it failed to deploy. Now I'm trying API15. It's still deploying after several minutes. I never had luck with Android emulators...

Comment: @Episodex Is this code in a dependency service? i.e. How are you accessing `File.ReadAllBytes` in `Forms` code?

Comment: It's shared project. So I use it just like that. While debugging on my Note 3 I see that the array is filled with the bytes. The memory stream is created. But then nothing is shown, whereas on A3 the image is displayed with the same code.

Comment: @SushiHangover here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37763367/set-image-source-to-file-in-external-storage-in-xamarin-forms/37763686#37763686

Comment: @jzeferino I finally installed SDK etc for API 21 and run emulator on it. It works ok.

Comment: Create a sample of the problem and upload it to github. I could test on other devices.

Comment: Ok, I will prepare and upload sample project in the evening. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to make sample project but Visual Studio went full rebel on me. Freshly created project will compile but will not run, types are not recognized, deploy doesn't work. It's not my day. I'm thinking more and more that I should have gone with native Android app from beginning... I will try again tomorrow evening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem.

But selecting a lower resolution in camera, the image works, I need select resolution < 9 Mpx and the image works, with resolutions biggers the image does not work.
It depend's of android version and device, it's a out of memory exception.

So, I resize the image taken with the camera and it works.

You can install FFimageLoading plugin and CachedImage control, i don't test it because i prefer resize the image, the app is larger with plugins.