# Universal Imageloader DisplayImage not showing image?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, universal-image-loader

I am working on a Xamarin Android project in Visual Studio and I am trying to display a picture for each object in a listView, but they are not showing up. When I debug it, it is getting all of the other details of the object, except for the image path and is showing up as `null`.

Currently I have the pictures in a **images** folder inside the project folder. And I listed the path like this

`string imageUri = @"C:\Users\aanwar\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ContosoLibrary\ContosoLibrary\images";`

And it seems to not find the location of the pictures. Should I place the pictures in the drawable folder instead of in the C:\ drive?

```
class BookListAdapter : BaseAdapter<BookDetailDTO>
{   
    Activity context;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.Instance;
    string imageUri = "C:/Users/aanwar/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/ContosoLibrary/ContosoLibrary/images";

    public BookListAdapter(List<BookDetailDTO> bookList, Activity context) : base()
    {
        this.context = context;
        imageLoader.Init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.CreateDefault(context));
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var item = items[position];

        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.BookRowView, null);

        convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.bookNameTextView).Text = item.Title;
        convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.priceTextView).Text = "$ " + item.Price;

        imageLoader.DisplayImage(imageUri + item.ImagePath + ".jpg",
            convertView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.bookImageView));

        return convertView;
    }
```

Can someone please assist me in this issue?

Comment: Not the exact soln. check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37763367/set-image-source-to-file-in-external-storage-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: That solution is not working out for my issue.

Comment: That's because, once you run your app on some device, you won't have access to your computer's drive, put the image in your drawable folder to display it. ImageView can directly display your image placed in drawable. check setImageResource method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And it seems to not find the location of the pictures. Should I place the pictures in the drawable folder instead of in the `C:\` drive?

When running your app on a device/emulator, the app won't have access to your local folder like `C:\XXX`.

The correct way to load the Image is to put the image into `Resource\drawable` folder and set the property of it to `AndroidResource`(by setting this VS will build the image into the final `apk` file).：

[image]

Then set it to the `ImageView` resource using the ResourceId:

```
ImageView mImageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.mImageView);
mImageView.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.tianyuan);
```