# How to set image view on the xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, imageview

Does anybody know how to set the image from the temp storage to the ImageView? I need to get this done as soon as possible. Thank you. I tried many way of doing but it is not helping at all.

```
namespace SubUnit
{
    [Activity(Label = "SubUnit", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        Button mbtnCam;
        const int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 0;
        global::Android.Net.Uri uriPhotoTaken;
        ImageView image1;


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
           mbtnCam= FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnCamera);
            mbtnCam.Click += MbtnCam_Click;
        }

        private void MbtnCam_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);

            if (intent.ResolveActivity(PackageManager) != null)
            {
                var storeImg= GetExternalFilesDir(global::Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures);

                var file = File.CreateTempFile("IMG_", ".bmp", storeImg);

                uriPhotoTaken = global::Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file);
                intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, uriPhotoTaken);

                StartActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);

            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37763367/set-image-source-to-file-in-external-storage-in-xamarin-forms) may help .

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to capture image from camera and display it in `ImageView`. You need to override `OnActivityResult` method to get the image data from camera intent, below code is to load a thumbnail image

```
protected override void OnActivityResult (int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if ((resultCode == Result.Ok) && (data != null)) {
        Bundle extras = data.Extras;
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.Get("data");
        image1.SetImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

And if you want save and load full size image then follow this [tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/camera_intent/take_a_picture_and_save_using_camera_app/)