# Xamarin.Forms load downloaded image to Image

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Good afternoon!
In my app I download image using this code:

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += (s, e) => {
                var bytes = e.Result; // get the downloaded data
                string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                string localFilename = "qr.png";
                string localPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, localFilename);
                File.WriteAllBytes(localPath, bytes); // writes to local storage
            };
            var url = new Uri("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=150x150&chl=" + name);
            webClient.DownloadDataAsync(url);
```

and store it to the local storage. In the next activity I want to set into the `<Image source="">` tag, but I don't know how to load image from storage. Help me please!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Image.Source to file in external storage in Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37763367/set-image-source-to-file-in-external-storage-in-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 0):

Is loading the image directly from its URL a second time critical ?

If not, I suggest passing the Url you just built to your next activity, and using [the example given in the official Xamarin doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#downloading-images) :

```
var webImage = new Image { Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("your Url")) };
```

If you really want to use the image you just stored in your localStorage you can use the [`FromFile` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.imagesource.fromfile?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_ImageSource_FromFile_System_String_) of `ImageSource` and put your path (using [Xamarin.essentials file system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-system-helpers?tabs=uwp) for example) in it :

```
new Image { Source = ImageSource.FromFile("your path") };
```

This attribute is mentioned at [the beggining of the documentation linked previously](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#displaying-images)