# Image from AppDataDirectory failed to be displayed in the Image view

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, maui

When my .net maui app starts it loads some images from the cloud and stores to `FileSystem.AppDataDirectory` folder. Then in offline mode it supposed to take them from the folder to display in the Image view, but the code does not work (binding will be used, but for the demo sake it's hardcoded):

```
    <Image WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30">
        <Image.Source>
            <FileImageSource File="/data/user/0/mytestapp/files/Icontest.svg" />
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
```

Same image works fine if loaded from the cloud when I replace File source to Url source.

`/data/user/0/mytestapp/files/` is what `FileSystem.AppDataDirectory` call returns, I just added file name to the end

Any idea if it's supported at all to load image files from the folder?

note: caching with url source does not serve the app requirements.

Comment: What is the OS?

Comment: Android 32, but it should not matter I hope

Comment: You have at least 2 problems here. One is the SVG format, that wont be displayed, the other will be the messed-up Android cache.

Answer (score 1):

SVG get pre-rendered and ship with your app. You have to reference them as PNG in your XAML. (On IOS, it wont even display if you use .svg) But this is not it.

Once replace your SVG resources with PNG. You will hit another problem.

The android will cache your files in your file system, and there is nothing you can do about it: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9773

There are two work arounds:

1. Change the name of the file every time, so it is never found.
2. Clear the cache by deleting everything from here: `Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, "image_manager_disk_cache");`

I think the negative effects of both workarounds are obvious. Fingers crossed that it gets fixed next year.

Answer (score 1):

At first, the Image control can't get the file from the device's external storage directly. The `FileImageSource` is used to get the image file in the project which is set as embedded resource.

So you can need to use a stream to read the file and then use the `ImageSource.FromStream` to set the image source.
Such as:

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
using (var source = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path))
{
   source.CopyTo(memoryStream);
}
image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => memoryStream)
```

But there is a bug about [ImageSource is not work when set Image.Source to file in external storage](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6525). Even the image file has been read as a stream, the image will not display. You can follow up this issue on the github.

Comment: I seriously doubt that this will make "Icontest.svg" render. Regardless of its location.

Comment: I tested with a new project and changed the dotnet_bot.png to dotnet_svg in the mainpage.xaml. The image will also show. @H.A.H.

Comment: This image is part of your project, the other sources are not. Also, if you test this on IOS you will see that it will not show. This is not a correct way to reference sources.

Comment: So we must use some other plugin such as FFImageLoading to convert the svg to png and then display it in the Image control? @H.A.H.

Comment: Yes. The documentation with this "SVG files are also supported" is so misleading, that...

Comment: All right, thanks for your explain. @H.A.H.

Comment: `> FileImageSource is used to get the image file in the project`. I was under impression another image source called `FromResource` is designed for that: it reads an image file embedded in an assembly as per its documentation. `FromFile` documentation says "reads an image from a local file", nothing about having to be part of the project (added at design time)

Comment: You can check [this answer about the `FromFile`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37763686/17455524). Actually, you had tried that. If the value is a path of the external storage, the image will not work. But if it is a static resource in the project, it will work correctly. @YMC